# sfdx force:source:convert is not converting CustomObject

Tags: custom-object, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, package.xml

I am a newbie to Salesforce and DX. We are not completely ready to move to DX at the moment, so, we are trying to do deployments (without ScratchOrgs and Packages) using package.xml.

Here is what I am trying to do:

1) Push the changes to a git branch, say, `feature/DeploymentReady`.

2) I am running a diff with the master to get the list of all the files that were changed -- `$ git diff --name-only HEAD^`.

3) Then I zip the files and copy them to a folder.

4) Unzip the files and convert them the package.xml format using the following command:

```
sfdx force:source:convert --rootdir .\force-app\main\default\test\ --outputdir ./codePkg
```

There is no error but when I see the CustomObject file, it doesn't have anything and because of which the `package.xml` which is created doesn't have any label related to my CustomObject.

Expected Custom Object: `Dreamhouse_Settings__c.object`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <customSettingsType>Hierarchy</customSettingsType>
    <enableFeeds>false</enableFeeds>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Einstein_Vision_Email__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Einstein Vision Email</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Email</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>LIFX_Token__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>LIFX Token</label>
        <length>255</length>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Text</type>
        <unique>false</unique>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>LIFX_URL__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>LIFX URL</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Url</type>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Light_Service_URL__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Light Service URL</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Url</type>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Push_Server_URL__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Push Server URL</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Url</type>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Slack_Opportunity_Webhook_URL__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Slack Opportunity Webhook URL</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Url</type>
    </fields>
    <fields>
        <fullName>Slack_Property_Webhook_URL__c</fullName>
        <externalId>false</externalId>
        <label>Slack Property Webhook URL</label>
        <required>false</required>
        <trackTrending>false</trackTrending>
        <type>Url</type>
    </fields>
    <label>Dreamhouse</label>
    <visibility>Protected</visibility>
</CustomObject>
```

Custom Object `Dreamhouse_Settings__c.object` after running `sfdx force:source:convert` command is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject/>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: I believe you'd have to make sure to include the object metadata itself (in the root folder of the object) in order to make it work. Still kind of sounds like a bug, so you might want to report this to the DX team on Trailblazer Community.

Comment: Thanks, @sfdcfox I will try your suggestion and also post to Trailblazer community.